# How create Activity with a few ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have to create Activity with ListView, when I click on item on ListView item and if this item has more items, new List sliding from left side to half of screen and so on...

It should be kind of this
http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple6/v4/d5/92/2a/d5922a96-fccf-508a-52fb-c3a21a8d8d4c/screen480x480.jpeg

Does somebody have some idea?
I don't need code just show me direction, but if you provide some simple example I will be glad to see it:) 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html 
This link has an implementation of how to make a listView. You would have 2 different activites with two listViews. And while implementing the onitemclick method of one listView you will have to set up an intent which will open the second listView activity. Did that gelp?
Even I am new to android so I hope that logic helped. I cannot explain without a code.